# URL encoding in admin overlays - breaks overlay

Tags: 7, modal-dialogs, debugging

I have a fresh install of Drupal 7 with no content, and a few extra modules installed. Recently as I've navigated on the admin side, the URLs for the overlays have escaped HTML in them, like this:

```
http://mywebsite.com/#overlay=%3Fq%3Dadmin/config
```

Which of course is supposed to mean

```
http://mywebsite.com/#overlay=?q=admin/config
```

But still, the overlay doesn't show up properly.

I've found a few [reports](http://drupal.org/node/1031798) of [this](https://drupal.org/node/1022670), but no fixes, other than to disable overlays. Can anyone offer anything?

What's tricky about this is that I can't get to administrative features *because the overlays can't show up*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm reasonably sure that the Overlay module doesn't work without clean URLs.

If `http://mywebsite.com/#overlay=admin/config` doesn't work, make sure that clean URLs are working properly.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this error is not related to **URL encoding**, but the lack of overlay module support when mod_rewrite is not properly configured in the Apache web server.

See http://drupal.org/node/1337420#comment-5238454.